# Failed Connection to Azure DevOps from VSIX Application

Tags: c#, azure, visual-studio-2015, azure-devops, vsix

I am working on a extension for Visual Studio 2015, currently i am working on the connection to Azure DevOps to create a Work Item like a Bug/Task/feature. Microsoft created a brief tuturial on how to create such things:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/integrate/quickstarts/create-bug-quickstart?view=vsts

However when i tried to implement this class in my VSIX Application i get this error:

```
An exception of type 'System.MissingMethodException' occurred in Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Method not found: 'Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializerSettings System.Net.Http.Formatting.BaseJsonMediaTypeFormatter.get_SerializerSettings()'.
```

The exception occurs on this line:

```
VssConnection vssConnection = new VssConnection(uri, clientCredentials);
```

For the credentials i use the following:

```
VssBasicCredential credentials = new VssBasicCredential("", personalAccessToken);
```

The strange thing is, when i made a new C# blank Console Application. Everything works fine, so i know it has nothing to do with my Personal Access Token, URI, code, etc.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Are you using Newtonsoft in your application? If you are check your bindings as you may have your version and the version that gets pulled down by their DLL.  Just a thought.

Comment: @Jamie Yes i am using Newtonsoft, I checked all the bindings and references, the version numbers are exactly the same...